# ANTLR any string variable prefix content

Tags: string, variables, antlr

I would like to know, why

```
expr:
a=(.*) 'ing' { System.out.println($a.text};
```

Does not work.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What are you trying to get expr to do? What input strings have you given it that are not working? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you're missing `);` in your embedded code. It's not:

```
{ System.out.println($a.text}
```

but:

```
{ System.out.println($a.text); }
```

You're also not really clear as to what "does not work" means, but I can make an educated guess. You're probably seeing `null` printed to the console. This is because you cannot assign a label to `.*` (`a=(.*)` is invalid). What you *can* do is move what `a` is supposed to point to, to a sub-rule:

```
expr
 : a=sub_rule 'ing' { System.out.println($a.text); }
 ;

sub_rule
 : /* ... something other than '.*' ... */
 ;
```

You should *not* be using `.*` inside parser rules, unless you know exactly what you're doing.